# S#arp Architecture - Rhino Security (unmapped class: Rhino.Security.IUser)

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, rhino-security

I'm using S#arp Architecture 1.6 and have implemented the Rhino Security integration as per

[Rhino Security - S#arp Architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/RhinoSecurity.ashx)

I'm using the latest build from Rhino.Commons

My Application_EndRequest method contains

```
ISession session = NHibernateSession.Current;
```

My ComponentRegister.cs contains

```
        container.Kernel.Register(

            Component.For<IAuthorizationService>()
                .ImplementedBy<AuthorizationService>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
            Component.For<IAuthorizationRepository>()
                .ImplementedBy<AuthorizationRepository>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
            Component.For<IPermissionsBuilderService>()
                .ImplementedBy<PermissionsBuilderService>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
            Component.For<IPermissionsService>()
                .ImplementedBy<PermissionsService>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
            Component.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>()
                .ImplementedBy<NHibernateUnitOfWorkFactory>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton),
            Component.For<Rhino.Commons.IRepository<User>>()
                .ImplementedBy<NHRepository<User>>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)
            );


        container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>()
            .Register(Component.For<ISession>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => NHibernateSession.Current)
            .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient));
```

I have also added RhinoSecurityPersistenceConfigurer() as per instructions.

The error I'm recieving on calling

```
UnitOfWork.Start()
```

is

```
An association from the table Permissions refers to an unmapped class: Rhino.Security.IUser
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this error may be?

Has anyone successfully integrated Rhino.Security with S#arp Architecture?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Rich

-- **Additional Details** --

Thanks for all the replies so far.

I've still not been able to resolve this, so thought I'd add more details.

In my Global.asax.cs I have

```
private void InitializeNHibernateSession()
{
  NHibernateSession.Init(
    webSessionStorage,
    new string[] { Server.MapPath("~/bin/SwitchSnapshot.Data.dll") },
    new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
    Server.MapPath("~/NHibernate.config"),
    null, null, new RhinoSecurityPersistenceConfigurer());
 }
```

RhinoSecurityPersistenceConfigurer :

```
public Configuration ConfigureProperties(Configuration nhibernateConfig)
{
  Security.Configure<User>(nhibernateConfig, SecurityTableStructure.Prefix);
  return nhibernateConfig;
}
```

I have an AuthorizationAttribute which calls

```
using (UnitOfWork.Start())
```

The error is occuring in NHibernateUnitOfWorkFactory.cs as

```
sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: You have to call `Security.Configure<User>` after `ConfigureNHibernate` but before `BuildSessionFactory`. You'll have to make a small change to S#arpArch's `NHibernateSession` source file to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped out.

In the end it was my own fault.

All I needed to do was to follow the [S#arp Architecture Instructions](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/Default.aspx?Page=RhinoSecurity&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) a little better.

From an old version of S#arp I had 2 config files hibernate.cfg.xml and NHibernate.config. I thought I still needed both, but all I needed was hibernate.cfg.xml for S#arp version 1.6 and mapped User.cs using Fluent NHibernate.

Other changes I did was in ComponentRegister.cs

```
        container.Kernel.Register( 
            Component.For<IAuthorizationService>()
                .ImplementedBy<AuthorizationService>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
            Component.For<IAuthorizationRepository>()
                .ImplementedBy<AuthorizationRepository>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
            Component.For<IPermissionsBuilderService>()
                .ImplementedBy<PermissionsBuilderService>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
            Component.For<IPermissionsService>()
                .ImplementedBy<PermissionsService>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
            Component.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>()
                .ImplementedBy<NHibernateUnitOfWorkFactory>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton),
            Component.For<Rhino.Commons.IRepository<User>>()
                .ImplementedBy<NHRepository<User>>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)
        );

        container.Kernel.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>()
            .Register(Component.For<ISession>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => NHibernateSession.Current)
            .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)
        );
```

Then use the following in my code.

```
        var authorizationService = IoC.Resolve<IAuthorizationService>();

        using (UnitOfWork.Start())
        {
        }
```

Comment: In what nsamespace I can find the class IoC you have used in IoC.Resolve<>()

Comment: Hi, the link http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/RhinoSecurity.ashx you provided above no longer points to Rhino.Security instructions.

Do you know another source for these instructions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need an NHibernate mapping for your User class (i.e. the class that implements the IUser interface).  You also need a table in the database with the correct fields for your User class.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I have the user class mapped in user.hbm.xml and the user class implementing IUser, they are all correctly mapped to the database fields also.

Comment: Should not you have the IUser interface mapped? That was the error said. Just guessing never worked with Rhino but that error is normally that the class/interface is not mapped correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have to let RS do some configuration work before the `SessionFactory` is created. Look at the second issue here http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture/browse_frm/thread/4093c52596f54d23/194f19cd08c8fdd7?q=#194f19cd08c8fdd7. It should get you in the right direction.